# html stretching div

Tags: html, stretching

I have this markup

```
<div id="line" width="100%; height: 44px;">
   <div id="identifier" style="position: absolute;left:0px width: 90px;">blabla</div>
   <div id="title" style="position: absolute; left: 90px;float: left; display:inline;">title</div>
   <div id="button" style="width:100px;float:right">gfgh</div>
</div>
```

How can I stretch div[id='title'] so it fills all the remainder space until next div (button)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set `position:relative` on div#line.
- Set `right:100px` on div#title.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing its CSS to this:

```
position: absolute; left: 90px; right: 100px; width: auto;
```

You will have to add `position:relative` to `#line` for this to work reliably (e.g. if `#line` changes its width in future).

Also note that this might not work reliably in older versions of IE, but it should work in theory.